# use group by concatenate in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using symfony2. My query is working in sql but it doesn't work in doctrine. Please help me to find the answer.

SQL query :

```
select v.date,v.time, sum(v.volume) as 'volume' 
from volume_vwus v 
where v.domain like 'www.vw.com' 
    and v.date between '2016-08-05' and '2016-08-29' 
    and v.cdn='EdgeCast' 
group by week(concat(v.date,v.volume));
```

DQL :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$lesVolumes = $em->createQuery("select v.date,v.time, sum(v.volume) as volume from AppBundle:Volume$tb v where v.domain like '%$domain%' and v.date between '$dateFrom' and '$dateTo' and v.cdn='$cdn' group by week(concat(v.date, ' ',v.time))");
```

Well, doctrine is showing an error

> near 'week(concat(v.date,': Error: Cannot group by undefined identification or result variable

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**DQL is not SQL**

DQL doesn't have `WEEK()` function as it's not a part of SQL language and it's not available in all RMDBS. It's MySQL's custom function.

You can use [Doctrine Extensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) which implements this  (and many other) custom functions of RMDBs, but this way you're making your code commited to this particular RMDBS.